# How do i program a "Distributed Transaction"?

Tags: .net, distributed-transactions

In the past all my db needs were solved by sqlite. Now designing a db that can potentially be large i looked into "Distributed Transaction". How do i program that? I found some results explaining what distributed transaction is but non explained how to program it.

I know in code i have a few transactions that i may want to batch into a larger transaction. I use .NET. How might i do something like create a user where his PK is in one database and his user information such as name and settings are in another database. This may be a separate question but if i have two functions. One updates a media description and the other updates the content which could be on the same server or separate. How i nest these transactions and only commit at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an introduction to the concept, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction).

For use in .NET, look at the [`System.Transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.aspx) namespace, especially the [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class. This will enable you to hook into the use of [DTC](http://tinyurl.com/yarkc8k). If you look at the [`System.Data.SQLite`](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) project then you can see how they have integrated DTC with SQLite.

Comment: Are you saying i can write a distributed transaction test right now with sqlite? If so i may very well do that.

Comment: As far as I know, `System.Data.SQLite` supports automatic DTC enlistment. So, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Approach that you described may lead to performance problems. Each request needs a transaction involving several databases. That is costly. Distributed transactions may be a good solution if you need, for example, involve a web service call and a DB request in the same transaction.

If you **will** need scalability to improve performance under heavy load in future, you might consider **clustering**. Instead of distributing parts of a single use-case among different servers, you will run simple (not distributed) transactions. And you will have benefit of scalability, because different requests will be handled by different servers.

There are different opinions about the main purpose of clustering and its applicability in various situations. I think it depends on domain and needs careful analysis. Some links regarding clustering:
[Database Clustering](http://www.ddj.com/database/184414502) by Neil McAllister,
[Overview of SQL Server 2000 Database Clustering using MSCS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlServerDBClusterMSCS.aspx) (outdated),
[Clustering (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(computing)) from Wikipedia, and [Clustering Algorithms](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/) - for general knowledge.

I would recommend you to take a look at [Errant Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/distributedComputing/abuse.pdf) by Martin Fowler (primarily talking about distributed computing, but also applicable to transactions), [Distributed Transactions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681205(VS.85).aspx) from MSDN, and these two opinions:

[Is Distribution really that bad?](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=44530) and
[(About) Martin Fowler's First Law of Distribution](http://www.jroller.com/dancres/date/20040419).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I hope will be useful and prevent you from serious mistakes.

Comment: Thanks to anonymous down-voter, I've found that my initial answer contained a wrong link. Now edited and added more info.

Comment: Warning: I provided different links to give general information from different points of view. If you decide to use clustering, I'm sure, you'll find more specific info on how to do it best in your situation.